# How update acf fileds with rest api Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-rest-api, acfpro

I am trying to update the custom fields (acf) of the Woocommerce product through the REST API:

```
$acf_data = [
 "fields" => [
  'demo_url' => 'http://myurl'
  ]
];
$woocommerce_tn->put('/wp-json/acf/v3/product/'.$product_tn->id, $acf_data);
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: There is a page explaining how to do that : https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/ Did you tried it ?

Comment: update_field () works if you are updating a field locally, but if you are trying to update the garment from another site using the Rest API it is not useful.

Answer (score 0):

Woocommerce API internaly use `WC_REST_Products_Controller`.

One of the internal steps of a product creation calls `update_additional_fields_for_object()` method and we can take advantage of that if we have a way to register our ACF fields in WordPress global var `$wp_rest_additional_fields`.

Here is a class I created to handle that:

```php
<?php

class Acf
{
    public const PRODUCT_FIELD_1 = 'field_650accdf92eaa';
    public const PRODUCT_FIELD_2 = 'field_650aaaaa761ed';

    public const PRODUCT_PROPERTIES = [
        self::PRODUCT_FIELD_1,
        self::PRODUCT_FIELD_2,
    ];

    public static function registerProductAcfFieldsForUpdate(): void
    {
        foreach (self::PRODUCT_PROPERTIES as $field) {
            self::registerProductRestForUpdate($field);
        }
    }

    protected static function registerProductRestForUpdate(string $attribute): void
    {
        register_rest_field(
            'product',
            $attribute,
            array(
                'update_callback' => 'Acf::updateAcfFieldsCallback',
            )
        );
    }

    /** @noinspection PhpUnused */
    public static function updateAcfFieldsCallback(
        $fieldValue,
        $product,
        $selector,
        $request,
        $objectType
    ): void {
        update_field($selector, $fieldValue, $product->get_id());
    }
}
```

Just call `Acf::registerProductAcfFieldsForUpdate()` from an appropriate hook like this maybe:

```php
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'Acf::registerProductAcfFieldsForUpdate' ) );
```

It works on my project